# Xubuntu 13.10 shuts down without asking when power button pressed

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, 13.10, xfce

Since I upgraded to Xubuntu 13.10, I can't seem to make the power button bring up the xfce shutdown dialog. I never had this problem on 13.04, but even after a clean install it persists.

When I use unity, the dialog comes up as expected, so the problem seems to be specific to xubuntu. Is anyone else experiencing this? Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: I recommend you to give the solution as an answer. You can also accept your answer within 24-48 hours. It would help others to get the solution easily!

Comment: It's a good question. Rather than "nevermind", you should move your edit into an answer and accept it yourself (as soon as the system lets you as @suarav-kumar points out). It's encouraged to answer your own questions if you find the answer. And the answer will likely get you some upvotes and rep.

Comment: For those interested, there is a bug report at launchpad, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1222021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to make `HandlePowerKey=ignore`, and that solved the issue!