# Xubuntu logs out on power button press

Tags: xfce, xfce4-power-manager

My Xubuntu logs out when I press the power button. I have changed the setting in Power Management to "Ask", but it still logs out.

Comment: Please have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/366358/change-power-button-to-ask-in-xubuntu-13-10