# Interactive prompt displayed but ignored on ACPI shutdown event (16.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, 16.04, shutdown, acpi

This is a very weird issue, and I've consulted the usual resources but found nothing.

When I press the shutdown button, I expect to see an interactive prompt -- e.g., "Shutdown / Reboot / Suspend / Cancel" or something of the sort (which I've had no problems with on other machines with older Ubuntus). I do see this prompt, but the system shuts down immediately regardless of whether I select an option or I select nothing at all.

I've done acpi_listen, and the event comes through normally. Nothing weird in syslog, but I'm sure that isn't the right place to look.

I suspect the problem is in Gnome/Unity, because setting the "Power Button Action" to "Nothing" in gnome-tweak-tool yields the expected result (the event is ignored). If it is set to any of the other options (suspend, logout, reboot, etc.), those work. Only the Interactive option misbehaves. I've also tried editing the corresponding field directly in dconf, with the same effects.

How can I diagnose this issue? And hopefully, fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you try the solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/366358/change-power-button-to-ask-in-xubuntu-13-10

Comment: Hey, that actually worked... I didn't find that when I was searching before. Thanks for the solution.